# Filling in datasets/ relative indexing

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this code that I want to be able to fill the datasets with the property isProjected with the value of 1. I have 3 datasets, lower estimate, projected and upper estimate but I want to be able to fill the Lower estimates and upper estimates with a background color of rgba(252, 0, 47, 0.2) and to leave the projected with no fill, fill: false. This code however is filling all the 3 datasets. "Upper Estimate" should be filled with -1, "Lower Estimate" with +1, and "Projected" should not be filled.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJL24.png)

This is what I tried.
This is the buildChart config code.

```
buildChartConfig(data: DataConfig): ChartConfiguration {
    
    const newData: ChartData = {
      ...data,
      datasets: data.datasets.map((value, i, array) => {
        const isProjected = (dataset: DatasetConfig) => dataset.isProjected;

        const result = {
          ...datasetDefaults(value, i, this.colorType),
          ...value,
          ...(isProjected(value) && {
            fill:
              isProjected(value) && i === array.findIndex(isProjected)
                ? '+1'
                : '-1',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(252, 0, 47, 0.2)',
          }),
        };
      
        return result;
      }),
    } as ChartData;
```

This is the dataset defaults code

```
export const datasetDefaults = (
  value: any,
  index: number,
  colorType?: ColorType | string
): ChartDataset => {
  const color = [
    '#bd081b',
    '#6C0510',
    '#CCCCCC',
    'rgba(252, 0, 47, 0.2)', //lower estimate
    '#FC002F',               //projected
    'rgba(252, 0, 47, 0.2)', //upper estimate
  ];
  const newIndex = index % color.length;
  const isProjected = value.isProjected || false;
  switch (colorType) {
    case ColorType.POINT:
      return {
        label: '',
        data: [] as Array<number | ScatterDataPoint | BubbleDataPoint>,
        backgroundColor: color,
        borderColor: color,
        fill: true,
      };
    case ColorType.SERIES:
    default:
      return {
        label: '',
        data: [] as Array<number | ScatterDataPoint | BubbleDataPoint>,
        backgroundColor: color[newIndex],
        borderColor: color[newIndex],
        fill: false,
      };
  }
```

And this is the code that gives the isProjected property the value of 1.

```
[
                  ...datasets,
                  {
                    label: dataPoint[legendField].toString(),
                    data: addToData(
                      newLabels.indexOf(dataPoint[dimField].toString()),
                      dataPoint[valueField]
                    ),
                    tooltips: addToTooltip(
                      newLabels.indexOf(dataPoint[dimField].toString()),
                      newToolTip,
                      dataPoint
                    ),
                    isProjected: dataPoint?.isProjected === 1,
                  },
                ];
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest that you do not post images as links; instead, just paste where  you want it to show up.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code:

```
buildChartConfig(data: DataConfig): ChartConfiguration {
  const newData: ChartData = {
    ...data,
    datasets: data.datasets.map((value, i, array) => {
      const isProjected = (dataset: DatasetConfig) => dataset.isProjected;

      const result = {
        ...datasetDefaults(value, i, this.colorType),
        ...value,
        ...(isProjected(value) && {
          fill: isProjected(value) ? '0' : '-1', // Adjusted the fill value
          backgroundColor: isProjected(value)
            ? 'rgba(252, 0, 47, 0)'
            : 'rgba(252, 0, 47, 0.2)',
        }),
      };

      return result;
    }),
  } as ChartData;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to respond to this. I tried your code and adjusted the fill value but the results were still the same, there was no fill on either of the projected values.

Comment: Would you be able to reproduce the problem on stackblitz? I would be in a better position to help.

Comment: I have since changed the code, I noticed that the flag I was using was not working. I now have the projected lower and projected showing the correct colors but for some reason projected upper is showing the projected colors. I believe I need a flag that doesn't come from the data base to group upper and lower projected for them to be able to have the same colors. I pasted the new code on the answer if you'd want to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
buildChartConfig(data: DataConfig): ChartConfiguration {
console.log('Original Data:', data);

const newData: ChartData = {
  ...data,
  datasets: data.datasets.map((value, i, array) => {
    const isProjected = (dataset: DatasetConfig) => dataset.isProjected;
    console.log('isProjected:', isProjected(value));
    console.log('Index:', i);
    console.log('Index of first projected:', array.findIndex(isProjected));

    const result: CustomChartDataset = {
      ...datasetDefaults(value, i, this.colorType), //lower
      ...value,
      ...(isProjected(value) &&
        i === array.findIndex(isProjected) && {
          fill: 'origin',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(252, 0, 47, 0.25)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(252, 0, 47, 0.25)',
          isProjected: true,
        }),
      ...(isProjected(value) && //projected
        i === array.slice().reverse().findIndex(isProjected) && {
          fill: false,
          backgroundColor: '#FC002F',
          borderColor: '#FC002F',
          isProjected: true,
        }),
    };

    console.log('Result:', result);
    return result;
  }),
} as ChartData;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a flag that takes the 1st and last is projected and gives the expected result.` buildChartConfig(data: DataConfig): ChartConfiguration {
console.log('Original Data:', data);

```
const newData: ChartData = {
  ...data,
  datasets: data.datasets.map((value, i, array) => {
    const isProjected = (dataset: DatasetConfig) => dataset.isProjected;
   
    const isFirstProjected = i === array.findIndex(isProjected);
    const isThirdProjected =
      i ===
      array.length - 1 - array.slice().reverse().findIndex(isProjected);

    const result: CustomChartDataset = {
      ...datasetDefaults(value, i, this.colorType), //lower
      ...value,
      ...(isProjected(value) &&
        (isFirstProjected || isThirdProjected) && {
          fill: 'origin',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(252, 0, 47, 0.25)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(252, 0, 47, 0.25)',
          isProjected: true,
        }),
      ...(isProjected(value) && //projected
        !(isFirstProjected || isThirdProjected) && {
          fill: false,
          backgroundColor: '#FC002F',
          borderColor: '#FC002F',
          isProjected: true,
        }),
    };
    console.log('Result:', result);
    return result;
  }),
} as ChartData;`
```